# Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality hold for discrete distributions?

Tags: statistical-significance, discrete-data, approximation, probability-inequalities

I am wondering whether [Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality) holds for discrete distributions? Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part of the statement of the inequality is raising doubts as to its validity in the discrete case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. See Theorem 11.6 in **Kosorok** (2008) *Introduction to Empirical Processes and Semiparametric Inference*:

**Theorem**: for any iid sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with distribution $F$, $$\mathrm{P}\left(\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \sqrt{n}\, \vert \mathbb{F}_n(t) - F(t)\vert > x\right) \leq 2 \exp(-2x^2),$$ for all $x>0$.